# Making an MFC application Mac OS X aware

Tags: macos, mfc, wine

I'm a software developer using WINE to run the Windows software on the Mac.  I have figured out how to determine if we are running under WINE, but is there a way to determine if we are running on a Mac and set the title bar at the top of the screen like other Mac applications?